# Multiplying an argument to a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A property of linear transformations $L$ is that $L(cu)=cL(u)$ for any $u∈V$ and $c\in\mathbb R$.

Suppose $u=[u_1, u_1^2]$. Is $L(cu) = [cu_1, c^2u_2^2]$ or $[cu_1, cu_2^2]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L(cu)=[cu_1,cu_2^2]$. When multiplying a vector that goes through a linear transformation, *ignore the content of the vector* and simply multiply each component by the given factor.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you also give me an example when this second condition is false? It seems like it is always true

Comment: @StannisBaratheon This second condition is a defining property of linear maps. It cannot be false. Note that I changed the title, since other authors will naturally have different definitions of linear maps, but all of them have this as an axiom.